# How to get alerted when Logic Apps connection becomes Invalid

Tags: azure, office365api, azure-logic-apps, office365connectors

I setup a Logic App workflow that runs each time I receive an email in my Exchange mailbox on Office 365.

From time to time my connection to Office 365 becomes invalid, e.g. expired token. This breaks my Logic App. Is there a way I can get alerted about invalid connections?

[image: Invalid connection in Logic App]

Comment: Is there any update on my below answer? If you find it useful please accept/upvote it, so that it can help other community members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to trigger an alert if your connections become invalid *(within logic apps)*

However, you can config an alert for your logic apps *(as a whole service)*.

### Alerts

You can set up an [Alert-Rules](https://msftplayground.com/2016/11/alerts-failed-azure-logic-apps/) in Logic apps to achieve this

[image]

### Diagnostic Logging/Alerts

You can also [enable the diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps#turn-on-diagnostics-logging-for-your-logic-app) to send all the logs to **Log analytics** *(previously called OMS)*

Then configure alerts in Log Analytics based on the `logs/telemetrics`.